# Unique containers per tweet - Twitterapi Jason Mayes

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter

the goal here is to place each tweet within its own unique container.  I want to break out of the box and scatter the feeds anywhere on my site.

Here is my attempt at this. Although it does not work, hopefully it gets the overall goal across.  Again, this is using the Jason Mayes twitter API.

Thank you

```
var config5 = {
  "id": 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
  "domId": '',
  "maxTweets": 12,
  "enableLinks": true,
  "showUser": false,
  "showTime": true,
  "dateFunction": '',
  "showRetweet": false,
  "customCallback": handleTweets,
  "showInteraction": false
};

function handleTweets(tweets) {
    // For loop the data.
    var items = [];
    var results;
    for (i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
        var tweets = [i];
        results = this({
            item = tweets[i]
        });
        items.push(results);
    }
    // insert the tweets into the DOM
    $("#twitter1").html(items.slice(0, 1));
    $("#twitter2").html(items.slice(1, 2));
    $("#twitter3").html(items.slice(2, 3));
}
```

A link to the work: http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/a72ykcg5/6/

Comment: In the title it's not clear what is the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work now, but you also have to enable jQuery in the jsfiddle:

```
var config5 = {
  "id": '624280239774961664',
  "domId": '',
  "maxTweets": 12,
  "enableLinks": true,
  "showUser": false,
  "showTime": true,
  "dateFunction": '',
  "showRetweet": false,
  "customCallback": handleTweets,
  "showInteraction": false
};

function handleTweets(tweets) {
    //var x = tweets.length;
    //var n = 0;
    //var element = document.getElementById('page');  
    var items = [];
    var results;

    for (i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
        items.push(tweets[i]);
    }
    // insert the tweets into the DOM
    $("#twitter1").html(items.slice(0, 1));
    $("#twitter2").html(items.slice(1, 2));
    $("#twitter3").html(items.slice(2, 3));
}

twitterFetcher.fetch(config5);

function dateFormatter(date) {
  return date.toTimeString();
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cs6bydr7/

Comment: Looks like i was very close!  Gotta work on my syntax!  Ill be coming back to this later today.